# Product Entity how to add properties asociacion

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am using **cbax/modul-manufacturers** plugin to get all products from the specific manufacturers on the product page. The problem is that I need product properties unfortunately this plugin during the creation criteria is not adding this associcion.
I checked and this plugin is bonded with **ProductPageLoadedEvent** and when will get all the products the plugin is adding them by:
`$event->getPage()->assign( ['cbaxModulManufacturers' => $manufacturerProducts]);`

The question is: How can I add a 'properties' association to this and have this data?

I tried to bind by different events and create a data resolver without success.

Comment: I would suggest you ask the plugin manufacturer directly. Basically, you would have to add it to the Criteria before the data is fetched via the EntityRepository. Still, here you need an event you can subscribe to, or you have to decorate the class.